# checking for occurrences of null between first value of array and last non null value of array?

Tags: java, arrays, tree, null

I am trying to test if a Binary Tree Array is complete. my idea was to take the array and check if there are any null values between the array[0] position and the index of the last non null value of the array. My question is how can I find the last non null element in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You could start scanning from the beginning, remembering the index of the last non-null you find.  Or start from the end working backwards; the first non-null's index will be 1 less than the first null's (unless they're all null).

But since all you care about is whether or not there is a null prior to a non-null, scan forward until you find a null, then keep going; if you hit a non-null before you get to the end, your BTA isn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
boolean foundNotNull = false;   // has a non-null value been found already?
for(int i = array.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
    if(array[i] == null && foundNotNull ) {
        return true;   // yes there are null values
    }
    if(array[i] != null) {
        foundNotNull = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of finding the first and last non-null values of an array.

```
    var first = myArray.filter(function(e, i, a) { return e != undefined;})[0];

    var last = myArray.reverse().filter(function(e, i, a) { return e != undefined;})[0];
```